# Wordpress File Upload Error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) worpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, file-upload

I installed a membership plugin named ARMember to my WordPress website. But it's file uploading filed is not working. When I try to upload a file, it fails and google console shows this error message.

"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"

you may check it here.

[BlueMoonGems](https://bluemoongems.com/register/)

Can someone please tell me how to fix this error..?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to be more specific about the issue. Generally, 404 means the server doesn't have the API endpoint to serve your request. Make sure ARmember plugin pointing to correct API endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

this is a problem that you need to contact the plugin creators about, this is not the place to look for a solution to such issue. However, you'll probably using an old version ( possible, but not sure ), the plugin is using wrong URL format to make ajax requests, which causes the error.